# keyboard and Mouse started some abnormal behavior

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, mouse

I am facing something really annoying with my ubuntu laptop for a couple of days. My keyboard and Mouse started some abnormal behavior, when I tried to write something with the keyboard on any site in my browser, I can't instead some shortcuts option of the browser appears depending on which key I pressed. If I tried to scroll with my mouse cycle, instead of scrolling it takes me previous pages. When I restart or log out and log in again this problem seems gone but it comes back again and again after few minutes of log in. I have no clue what is happening. I have upgraded ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04, not only that but also upgraded my Linux kernel for this issue but no result.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a stuck ctrl or alt key. Check both of you ctrl keys, alt & alt gr keys are moving as expected, and don't bind.

Comment: Make a bootable USB Key and start from that see if the separate OS works.

Comment: Try running`xev` to identify if it's the case of a stuck Mod key.

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks! you are right. I pressed Alt and Ctrl a couple of times. Now everything seems under control. Poor me.